# Counting Occurrences within a Range in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Table "03_DataSelection-Appended" with several Fields example shown below:

AlarmID, AlarmTime, HourEarly, HourLate, NumAlarmsEarly

244, 10/7/19 1:25 PM, 10/7/19 12:25 PM, 10/7/19 2:25 PM, 1

245, 10/7/19 1:39 PM, 10/7/19 12:39 PM, 10/7/19 2:39 PM, 2

246, 10/7/19 1:47 PM, 10/7/19 12:47 PM, 10/7/19 2:47 PM, 3

247, 10/8/19 10:17 PM, 10/8/19 9:17 PM, 10/8/19 11:17 PM, 1

248, 10/8/19 10:17 PM, 10/8/19 9:17 PM, 10/8/19 11:17 PM, 2

249, 10/14/19 9:24 AM, 10/14/19 8:24 AM, 10/14/19 10:24 AM, 2

250, 10/14/19 9:24 AM, 10/14/19 8:24 AM, 10/14/19 10:24 AM, 2

251, 10/14/19 9:25 AM, 10/14/19 8:25 AM, 10/14/19 10:25 AM, 4

252, 10/14/19 9:25 AM, 10/14/19 8:25 AM, 10/14/19 10:25 AM, 4

What I'd like to do is Count the number of Rows that has an AlarmTime value between the AlarmTime and HourEarly for Every AlarmTime and add that value to the Table/Query as an additional Field [NumAlarmsEarly]

The Readout for the first few is shown in the field above [NumAlarmsEarly]

I have tried the standard adding AlarmTime twice to a Query and then having the second one be the "Count" but this is not returning the desired output for some reason.

Here is the code that I've tried with the Query Named "04_AlarmCounts"

```
SELECT A.AlarmTime, A.HourEarly, A.HourLate, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '03_DataSelection-Appended' B WHERE B.AlarmTime Between A.AlarmTime AND A.HourEarly) AS NumAlarmsEarly
FROM '03_DataSelection-Appended' AS A;
```

PART 2 - Adding Additional Variables

I've attempted to add additonal calcs within the nested loop but keep getting a syntax error the code I think I'm closest with is as follows:

```
SELECT A.AlarmTime, A.HourEarly, A.HourLate, A.MidPointBegin, A.MidPointEnd,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [03_DataSelection-Appended] B WHERE B.AlarmTime Between A.AlarmTime AND A.HourEarly) AS NumAlarmsEarly
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [03_DataSelection-Appended] B Where B.AlarmTime Between A.AlarmTime AND A.HourLate) AS NumAlarmsLate
FROM [03_DataSelection-Appended] AS A;
```

I've attempted using a UNION SELECT as well as messing with the () to include both SELECT statements in the (). I'm assuming the solution is something pretty close.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is nothing in the first three that makes each one unique.  Unless there are milliseconds/microseconds that are not revealed.  Also, I cannot copy the PNG picture into my access db, so I need data that more significant places, and it needs to be pasted in with braces, so that I can replicate the problem.  The "answer" list does not give a row identifier.

Comment: I currently do not have a unique ID for these Data points. Is that something that I should consider adding in order for this to work? Also i am working on figuring out how to get this to you in editable format

Comment: I think that all that is wrong with your part 2 is you are missing a comma after `NumAlarmsEarly` to separate it from the next calculated field.

Comment: Wow... can't believe that was it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need a subquery that has SQL looking like this:

```
SELECT A.AlarmTime, A.HourEarly, A.HourLate, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [03_DataSelection-Appended] B WHERE B.AlarmTime Between A.AlarmTime AND A.HourEarly) AS NumAlarmsEarly
FROM [03_DataSelection-Appended] AS A;
```

Regards

Comment: I've tried to copy and paste into my code and i'm getting an error. I've updated my original post to have the proper Table Name as well as the code that i've tried to update to make it work.... I've also added the query name "04_AlarmCounts" (don't know if that makes a difference sorry I'm a beginner trying to piece my way through this).

Comment: It is because of the name of the base query that you are using. Just wrap it in square brackets as I have done in my modified answer, and it works OK.

Comment: Your solution worked thank you! If i wanted to add additional Columns calcs to this how would i do it? For example adding the same Calculation but for the HourLate column instead of HourEarly. I'm sure its something simple... I've copied my attempted code in the initial Thread as "PART 2"